# Unable to find the value in call stack when I run debugger

Tags: javascript

[image]

```js
var output ="";

for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
  {
    
    if(i%3 === 0)
      {
  debugger;
        output+="Fizz";
        console.log(output);
      }
    
      
  }
```

I'm trying to run this code in chrome Dev console. and I added debugger to see how my code working but in the "CALL STACK" values are not showing up I can only see message like "ANONYMOUS" .. Could anyone help me to find out how could I see my program flow in call stack !!

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Because you ran the code from the console and is all immediate (with no functions), there _is_ no call stack. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: If you add a break point in your javascript code you will see your call stack.

Comment: @DocMax Hi I'm just trying to see the output after each iteration !

Comment: @HaydenPassmore can you show me how to do that !! , thanks !!

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) Link should show you how to do it but @DocMax is correct you wont have a call stack as your code is not being called from any function. To see the output of each iteration you need to look at your console which is at the bottom of the dev tools window.

Comment: @sni you have put debugger at wrong place, execution will go to your debugger only when your if condition is satisfied. i.e when i value is 3. Put your debugger before if condition to see all iterations and their values. –

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the values after each pass in the loop, start with what you have and expand the "Global" item in the "Scope" section at the right of the console. That will show you all the global values (which yours are since your code is not in a function). Then hit the blue "resume" button to continue until the next time the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

[image][[image]]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm3JT.png)You need to put your code in a function to see in stack like below, if you are running directly from global context it will show anonymous.

```
function Hello() {
        var output ="";

        for(var i=1;i<=20;i++)
        {

            if(i%3 === 0)
            {
                debugger;
                output+="Fizz";
                console.log(output);
            }


        }
    }
    Hello();
```

Comment: But when I run this , why the starting value of "" i "" representing as 3 instead of 1 in the debugger window

Comment: May be you are looking at wrong place :), I am attaching image of developer tool you can see where exactly to look at.

Comment: @sni you have put debugger at wrong place, execution will go to your debugger only when your if condition is satisfied. i.e when i value is 3. Put your debugger before if condition to see all iterations and their values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and look up in the debugger to notice the difference.

Each time you invoke a function, JS engine will create a new execution context and put it on the stack.

```
(function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      debugger;
      output += "Fizz";
      console.log(output);
    }
  }
})();
```